# One command line argument in C

Tags: c

write c program that accepts one command line argument (your first name) and prompts the user for user input (your last name), then print ""Welcome to operating systems,   "" to the screen.

Can anyone help me with this question? I know its using something like this from the below,  but I dunno how to print out the thing? Can anyone help by giving the full answer? Thanks in advance.

```
int main (int argc, int *argv[])
```

Comment: We can help you with what you've done, but you don't appear to have done anything. Do you have any code past the declaration of `main`?

Comment: Review your class materials. Your instructor won't have given you this assignment out of the blue, it will have been covered in class and/or the book.

Comment: The code you have provided in the question is just the function declaration for 'main' in C

Comment: It might help you understand if you know that the `argv` argument is really `char *argv[]`, i.e. an array of strings (not an array of pointers to `int`). But as noted, it should have been covered in class or in your book, and if not there are several thousands of tutorials and examples in how to handle command-line arguments on the wide-open Internet.

Answer (score 1):

`argc` is an integer that represents the number of command line arguments passed in to the program. It is the argument count, hence the name. `*argv[]` (or `**argv` depending on developer preference) represents the actual arguments. The proper name for `argv` is argument vector, which makes sense if you're familiar with that particular data type.

The first argument passed in, `argc = 1` is the program's name. Argc is always at least one because argv will always contain at a minimum the name of the program.

To answer your question, you need to pass in a second command-line argument, `argc = 2`, where argv[1] equals the user's first name. We can accomplish that like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // This line will print out how many command line arguments were passed in.
    // Remember that it will always be at least one because the name of the program
    // counts as an argument.
    printf("argc: %d", argc);

    // Remember that you want the second argument in argv,
    // so you have to call argv[1] because arrays in C 
    // are 0-index based. Think of them as offsets.
    printf("\nWelcome, %s", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

This should get you started. All you need to do now is write the code to read the string from the standard input and output it to the console.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, your really helped me. My lecturer expect me to know all of these but I only learned some basics about C programming. Can I ask one more question, do you use scanf to ask for the user to input the name? So that it will print out Welcome, name-name ?

Comment: Scanf is one way to receive user input, yes. Just make sure you use the address-of operator when you do. It's a common beginner mistake to leave it out, so the user enters data but it doesn't actually change the variable it's supposed to.